# Problems with speeding up loop in R

Tags: r, performance

I have a particularly big dataset which consists of 3.7 mio rows and 76 string columns.

I want to compare the above row with the below row in terms of whether they match and have written this code. The number of same patterns of the above and the below row should be indicated.

```
   a <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
   b <- c("b","b","b","b","a","b","b","b","b")
   c <- c("c","c","c","c","a","a","a","b","b")
   d <- c("d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d")
   features_split   <- data.frame(a,b,c,d); features_split
   ncol = max(sapply(features_split,length))
   safe <- as.data.table(lapply(1:ncol,function(i)sapply(features_split,"[",i)))
   nrow(safe)
   df <- safe
   LIST  <-list() 
   LIST2 <-list() 
   for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) 
   { 
   LIST[[i]] <-df[i+1,] %in% df[i,] 
   LIST2[[i]] <- length(LIST[[i]][LIST[[i]]==TRUE]) 
   } 
   safe2   <- unlist(LIST2)
   not_available <- rowSums(!is.na(safe))
```

It takes forever to run that loop. How can I improve?
(about 1 hour for 100.000 rows, but I have more than 3.7 mio)

Grateful for anything, 
Tobi

Comment: First of all: is `a,b,c,d` columns or rows? If columns then `data.frame(a,b,c,d)` is ok, if rows then use `data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))`. Please clean your post :)

Comment: Yes, please try to make your example clear in term of input and desired output...

Comment: You probably will want to do something more like `all.equal(df[i],df[i+1])` , but you need to provide a reproducible output as well as input.

Comment: well, you can probably assume that the output from this code is the desired output ...

Comment: Do you have multiple cores available?  Parallelism could help here.

Comment: **BTW**: you have significant code inefficiency. `ncol` is a function, and though you can mask a function with a variable, it happens to be doing what you want but *considerably* faster. Replace `ncol = max(sapply(features_split,length))` with `nc <- ncol(features_split)` and use `nc` thereafter.

Additionally, you are pre-allocating lists (`LIST` and `LIST2`), but are gaining no efficiency by allocating them without a known length. The setup of `LIST` is a little more complicated since it's a list of lists, but for the second you could use `LIST2 <- integer(nrow(df)-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a **data.frame**

Proof of concept, using `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(4)
nr <- 1000
mydf <- data.frame(a=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
                   b=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
                   c=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
                   d=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
matches <- vapply(seq.int(nrow(mydf)-1),
                  function(ii,zz) sum(mydf[ii,] == mydf[ii+1,]),
                  integer(1))
head(matches)
## [1] 0 3 4 2 1 0
sum(matches == 4) # total number of perfect row-matches
## 16
```

In `matches`, the integer in position `i` indicates how many strings from row `i` exactly match the corresponding string from row `i+1`. A match of `0` means no matches at all, and (in this case) `4` means the row is a perfect match.

Taking it a bit larger for a demonstration of time:

```
nr <- 100000
nc <- 76
mydf2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:4], nr*nc, repl=TRUE), nc=nc),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(mydf2)
## [1] 100000     76
system.time(
    matches2 <- vapply(seq.int(nrow(mydf2)-1),
                       function(ii) sum(mydf2[ii,] == mydf2[ii+1,]),
                       integer(1))
    )
##    user  system elapsed
##  370.63   12.14  385.36
```

### Using a **matrix** instead

If you can afford to do it as a **matrix** (since you have a homogenous data type of "character") instead of a data.frame, you'll get considerably better performance:

```
nr <- 100000
nc <- 76
mymtx2 <- matrix(sample(letters[1:4], nr*nc, repl=TRUE), nc=nc)
dim(mymtx2)
## [1] 10000    76

system.time(
    matches2 <- vapply(seq.int(nrow(mymtx2)-1),
                       function(ii) sum(mymtx2[ii,] == mymtx2[ii+1,]),
                       integer(1))
    )
##     user  system elapsed 
##    0.81    0.00    0.81
```

(Compare with `370.63 user` from the previous run.) Scaling it up to full-strength:

```
nr <- 3.7e6
nc <- 76
mymtx3 <- matrix(sample(letters[1:4], nr*nc, repl=TRUE), nc=nc)
dim(mymtx3)
## [1] 3700000      76
system.time(
    matches3 <- vapply(seq.int(nrow(mymtx3)-1),
                       function(ii) sum(mymtx3[ii,] == mymtx3[ii+1,]),
                       integer(1))
    )
##     user  system elapsed 
##   35.32    0.05   35.81 

length(matches3)
## [1] 3699999
sum(matches3 == nc)
## [1] 0
```

Unfortunately, still no matches, but I think 36 seconds is considerably better for 3.7M than an hour for 100K. (Please correct me if I'm made an incorrect assumption.)

(Ref: win7 x64, R-3.0.3-64bit, intel i7-2640M 2.8GHz, 8GB RAM)

Comment: BTW: the max number of matches was 40 (out of 76). Not surprisingly, the histogram of `matches3` shows a very normal distribution with a mean of 19 and a standard deviation of 3.78.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the Answer. Otherwise, feel free to elaborate on any part that I missed.