# R search values of row above

Tags: r, match

I have a question: this answer seems to work well for comparing the values of the previous with the current row - but ONLY the values in the same column.

[Problems with speeding up loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969561/problems-with-speeding-up-loop-in-r)

If you want to compare the values of row2, column2 with any of the columns in row1, how could this be done? Is there a solution?

```
set.seed(4)
nr <- 1000
mydf <- data.frame(a=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
               b=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
               c=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
               d=sample(letters[1:3], nr, repl=TRUE),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This would be the matrix, however, it should be counted how many of the values in a row match the values of any previous row. E.g.,

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
c,e,h,i,j,NA,NA
NA,i,NA,NA,a,f,NA
```

Sample output: 
    NA,2,1

--> this would mean two matches, "c" and "e". Please not that there should be only unique character values in each field of the matrix and that there should be "NAs" which should not be counted as "match".

IMPORTANT: It should ONLY be searched in the previous row!

THANKS in advance!

Comment: What's the point of setting a seed and generating a data set if you then show us unrelated example output? You could make this clearer by demonstrating exactly what you hope to get as output given your data.

Comment: Essentially I think what you're asking is: "How can I efficiently count, for each row of a data.frame, the number of elements that occur in earlier (higher) rows?". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry, for being unprecise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="a,b,c,d,e,f,g
c,e,h,i,j,NA,NA
NA,i,NA,NA,a,f,NA", sep=",", header=FALSE)

DF1 <- as.data.frame(t(DF))

mapply(function(x, y) length(na.omit(intersect(x, y))), 
        DF1[, -1], DF1[, -ncol(DF1)])
#V2 V3 
# 2  1
```

Comment: Nice approach, and a tad quicker than mine. I tend to forget how simple it is to solve these problems by just staggering the entire vector.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to iterate over row numbers, checking for each row which elements occur in previous rows:

```
counts <- c(NA, sapply(2:nrow(mydf), function(i) {
  sum(match(mydf[i, ], mydf[i-1, ], incomparables=NA, nomatch=0) > 0)
}))

head(counts, 20)

## [1] 0 3 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 4 4 3 4 2 4 4 2 2
```

Comment: Dear jbaums, I am sorry, one add on: just in the row above it should be searched. is there also a way to do this quicker? (there are 500.000 rows and 40 columns)

Comment: Please correct the question then, which reads: "how many of the values in a row match the values of *any previous row*". I've updated my solution.